# Returing ModelAndView vs DTO from the Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand the best way to render UI with the result from the Spring Controller. Usually if I am not using AJAX call and rendering whole page with the response from the controller I return the model and view. But whenever I am updating part of the JSP I use AJAX call and return the response as DTO with @ResponseBody and extract DTOs field to plugged in to the HTML elements.

So my question is what is a efficient way to send response from controller so that I don't have to write code to plugged in response in HTML elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bhaskara - Thanks for your suggestion. Yes we can definitely use JSON as the response.

But my question was different. Its about returning view inf AJAX call so that part of the div can be updated. After writing simple skeleton app it seems we can achieve this by:

1. Create master page with divs.
2. Create separate JSP page to load on div. Use JSTL (or any other tool) to
3. Return ModelAndView (JSP with modal) from the controller.
4. In AJAX success callback function load the div with the JSP.

Hope other can benefit from this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

You can return application/json as the response. As part of your Spring project have Jackson libraries in the classpath and then return your model (DTO ?) as@ResponseBody. Spring automatically converts your Model into json and returns it as a HTTP Response (to your AJAX call). Javascript (especially JQuery) has an excellent support for parsing JSON